# why toMillis() function returning -1 in java

Tags: java, android, time

In android, while running the below code snippet, date3 returns -1

```
booking_year2 = 2038;
booking_month2 = 1;
booking_day2 = 17;
Time t = new Time();
t.set(booking_day2, booking_month2 - 1, booking_year2);
long date3 = t.toMillis(false);
//date3 returns 2147451300000 as expected

//But if we run with values:
booking_year2 = 2038;
booking_month2 = 1;
booking_day2 = 18;
//date3 returns -1
```

While, the Time object 't' have expected value in all conditions, the long value returned by toMillis() function is only -1.
And also, for all the upper values of date after jan 19, 2038, the toMillis() function returns only -1 and not the expected value.

I didn't understood and didn't found any suitable reason or solution for this.
Please let me know, if I am doing anything wrong or is there any other way to find the millisecond values after this date.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem ?

Answer (score 2):

That is the **year-2038-problem** which affects the class `android.text.format.Time` ([android class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)). The problem is typical for UNIX. And the documentation of the class says:

"It is modelled after struct tm, and in fact, uses struct tm to implement most of the functionality."

So it uses in the background a [C++-solution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) which is also widespread on UNIX-systems. This datatype has only 32 bits, so in year 2038 integer overflow will happen. Finally you can hope on a future bugfix, see following bug report of Android:

[Issue 37653](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37653):   android.text.format.Time not year 2038 safe

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), the open-source third-party library.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2099, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, DateTimeZone.UTC );
long millis = dateTime.getMillis();
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "millis: " + millis );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2099-01-02T03:04:05.000Z
millis: 4071006245000
```